# C++ inline resulted in undefined reference

Tags: c++

t.h

```
#ifndef __T_H__
#define __T_H__

class A
{
    int j;
public:
    A(int i); 
};

#endif
```

t.cpp

```
#include "t.h"

inline A::A(int i):j(i){}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "t.h"

int main(void)
{
    A a(2);

    return 0;
}
```

compile:

```
$ g++ t.cpp main.cpp -o main
/tmp/ccRjri7I.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `A::A(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I remove the inline from the implementation, it'ok. don't know why is this happen.

Comment: If you want let the compiler to inline it, define it in the header. (note: marking something with inline keyword doesn't mean, that it will be inlined.)

Comment: You should define the constructor as inline in the header, or no inline in cpp

Comment: You have to put `inline` keyword in the class definition to do this; and the function body must be visible to all code that calls it.

Answer (score 5):

Inlines must be defined in the same translation unit where they are used.  By defining your "inline" function in the .cpp file, it is only usable in the same .cpp file.  You need to move it either to the header file, or some special "inlines" file that some projects prefer to keep their implementation details a bit more hidden (you'd then `#include` that inlines file, either in your header or in main.cpp).